# Topology, metric spaces, equivalence of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The open $n$-cube is the set of all points 
$x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$
such that $0<x_i<1$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$.
Prove that the open $n$-cube, considered as a subspace of $(\mathbb R^n,d)$, is topologically equivalent to
$(\mathbb R^n,d)$.

I'm working on a group of problems and got to this one and am completely lost on what to do. What is an $n$-cube? is it basically another way to write all the numbers in between $0$ and $1$? what function is on-to, $1$ to $1$, and continuous from $(0,1)$ to the reals? I'm dying out here, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: As the definition says, the open $n$-cube is the subset of $n$-dimensional space where all coordinates are in $(0,1)$. So the open $1$-cube is $(0,1)$, the open $2$-cube is $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, and so on. I'd think about the homeomorphism $(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ a little harder-it actually should be quite intuitive that it's true, so you shouldn't worry about explicit formulas to begin with.

Comment: Well i think i agree that it's true. It's obviously possible to link an open interval to R in 1 dimension but i have no clue how to PROVE it is true for n-dimensions

Comment: OK, so then it's time to write down a map in one dimension, which you will be able to generalize to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: A map f(x) = ln ( (1/x) - 1) is bijective from 0,1 to R but i don't know how to prove that is true or generalize it for multiple n

Comment: or f(x) = (2x-1)/(x-x^2)

Answer (score 1):

Observe first that the function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$, given by
$$
f(x)=\log\big(\log (x^{-1})\big),
$$
is a homeomorphism (also $C^\infty-$diffeomorphism) between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$, and hence
$$
F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\big(\,f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)\big) : (0,1)^n\to\mathbb R^n,
$$
is also a homeomorphism between $(0,1)^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$.